# MySQL JOIN query with COUNT unexpected results

Tags: mysql, left-join

Not sure my logic is working quite right on this one. I have a table `Documents` that has a unique ID for each item and the name of the document. Then I have another table `DocVotes` that stores user votes on the document (one vote per record) There is a field `Vote` that is a `BOOL` (1 for YES and 0 for NO).

I am trying to check if a particular user `MemberID` has voted on the document before, obviously you can't vote on your own document (Checked by excluding `AuthorID`)

Here is the query I am trying

```
SELECT d.ID, d.Name, COUNT(dv.MemberID) 
FROM Documents AS d
LEFT JOIN DocVotes AS dv ON dv.ItemID=d.ID
    AND dv.MemberID=32
WHERE d.Status =  'Proposed'
    AND d.AuthorID<>32
```

What I think it should be doing: Get the `ID`, `Name`, and count the number of votes cast by `MemberID` (32 in this case) Then simply check the count and if the count is 0 then that would mean that the user has not voted yet, if 1 then they have (You can only vote once).

However I am getting back a count of 6 yet only 1 vote was cast by this user on this particular document. So obviously this is counting more that just that entry... (I am only getting 1 row back)

Thoughts?

Comment: You may need 1) a fiddle so we can check 2) a `GROUP BY`

Comment: I actually just tried that and I got back 6 rows with the expected results. I left out the `GROUP BY d.ID` and now it works great. It's always the obvious that gets us... Thanks.

Comment: Good! I put it in answer so that question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to note what has been talked on comments:

Try using `GROUP BY d.ID`:

```
SELECT d.ID, d.Name, COUNT(dv.MemberID) 
FROM Documents AS d
LEFT JOIN DocVotes AS dv ON dv.ItemID=d.ID
    AND dv.MemberID=32
WHERE d.Status =  'Proposed'
    AND d.AuthorID<>32
GROUP BY
    d.ID
```